# C defining function pointer with pointer agruments

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with:

```
typedef *void (*pfun)(**int, *float);
```

as far as I understand the problem is that I can't pass the function the pointers as

```
typedef *void (*pfun)(int, float);
```

doesn't generate an error but I have no idea why that is the case.

Comment: Did you mean `int**` and `float*`?

Comment: @UchiaItachi: And `void*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question for new programmers.  The de-reference operator has several uses in defining pointers.

First, it can be placed BEFORE a variable name.  This implies that the variable is a pointer to a data type, such as: `int *X;` means that X points to RAM which contains an integer value.

Second, it can appear to stand alone as part of a cast statement: `(int *) Y` which means that the contents of `Y` are to be interpreted as a pointer to an integer.

Third, and probably its most obtuse usage is to indicate a pointer to a function. For example,

```
int (*func_ptr_ret_int)(void);
```

Declares to C that the variable `func_ptr_ret_int` points to a function that does NOT take any parameters and returns an integer.  In this example, `func_ptr_ret_int` has yet to be assigned a value and so it should be assumed to contain garbage.

A fourth usage, is to indicate a double pointer: `int **Z;` declares that Z points to a another pointer(un-named) which in turn points to an integer.

Finally, I would recommend that you defer using `typedef` statement until you can code a declaration "natively".  That is, `typedef` only defines a new data type is does NOT allocate storage or assign values.

With this in mind your two statements could be coded as:

```
void (*pfun1)(int **, float *); // pfun1 points to a function that returns void
                                // and uses a double ptr to inf and ptr to float


void *(*pfun2)(int, float);     // pfun2 points to a function that returns a void
                                // pointer and accepts int and float parameters.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `int *func_ptr_ret_int(void);` is a declaration of a function that returns pointer to int. The definition of a function pointer should be `int (*func_ptr_ret_int)(void);`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `void*` ,  `int**` and `float*`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using valid C/C++ syntax for pointer declaration in the following expression:

```
typedef *void ( *pfun )( **int, *float );
```

**Recall:** Points are declared in the following format:

```
datatype *identifier
```

... and hence your type definition should be written as:

```
typedef void* (*pfun)( int**, float* );
```

**Remark:** Spacing does not matter when declaring pointers, hence the following are equivalent:

```
datatype *identifier
datatype* identifier
```

... however you will find that *most* programers agree that it is a good practice to do the first pointer declaration as it communicates that the identifier is a pointer to a data type. This practice becomes more apparently useful when declaring multiple pointer on one line. Example:

```
int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3; // Declaring 3, valid, pointers to integers.
int* ptr1, ptr2, ptr3; // Declares 1, valid, pointer to an integer and 2 other integers.
```

Answer (score 0):

typedef void* (*pfun)(int **i, float *f); This means function pointer which has int ** , float * as arguments and returns void *.  But in your post the dereference operator is not in proper place.